# Visual Studio Code or PyCharm for python development?

Tags: python, ide, visual-studio-code

I used PyCharm for quite a while until someone suggested VSC. I've been using VSC ever since. I'm not sure which one to use for Python development. Here are some pros and cons I've found.

## VSC

#### Pros

- Has plugins, allowing for enhanced development.
- Supports seemingly infinite languages.

#### Cons

- PyLint can get annoying at times, and you can't turn it off without bad issues¹.
- It's hard to run.

## PyCharm

#### Pros

- It's designed mainly for python.
- You can easily run python files

#### Cons

- ***It's designed mainly for python.*** There isn't too much support for other languages.
- It's buggy with changing the interpreter. It doesn't save properly, meaning that the interpreter you choose when you make a project is usually the interpreter you

¹You can't run it without spending 2 minutes setting up the shell at the bottom.

Comment: What OS? Honestly, Notepad++ (or some comparable Linux editor) along with the standard interactive interpreter have been fine enough for me for vast majority of the Python code I've written/worked with. Few times I've used Visual Studio (the big one -- being primarily a C++ dev, i've got a few versions around) with Python tools installed... I guess it worked alright, but since I mostly use Python for quick prototyping or answering SO questions, it was usually too much (compared to adding a tab to already open text editor, and popping up a new console if at all needed).

Comment: As a side note: Get familiar with the documentation of whatever language/library you use, learn to understand what the code you write does. Then all you really need is a piece of paper and something to write with (when I was a kid, that was what I did most of the time, since for many years, getting a machine it was meant for was out of question --  I could use it once in a long while). | "spending 2 minutes setting up the shell" -- write a script. And 2 minutes -- IMHO inconsequential, considering how much time you'll spend working on the code.

Comment: And finally, I'd say try all the possibilities and find out what suits you the best. I've worked at Skype in the C++ backend team, writing server code running on Debian in production. We had people using Vi, people using Emacs, people developing exclusively on remote machine as well as people developing on their own machines, people using Eclipse, people using KDevelop, people working on Macs, and who knows what else. That was a team of around 15 devs and it worked without issues -- we had a standardized build system, but what you used for editing was basically irrelevant.

Comment: @DanMašek Windows 7

Comment: PyCharm is quite heavy weight (takes long to startup and be usable), which is for me a bit of a downside. I usually use both. If I know I spend a couple of hours in code I startup PyCharm and if I just want to edit some lines and do some smaller stuff I use VSCode

Comment: @dan you really don't see the befit of an IDE? I haven't used command lien for decades, for productivity reasons.  Can you run the debugger from the interpreter? I really wouldn't know. You certainly can't refactor, beyond global rename in Notepad++ (which is my goto ***text editor***, but hardly an IDE). Give PyCharm a chance - or any other IDE for that matter, and you won't look back

Comment: @Person you mention other languages, but [don't tell us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun) which, if any, you use. That would help us to help you. Personally, I use Eclipse for C, C++, Angular Js and PHP, because that is what I use at work. I use to use it for Python, until I discovered PyCharm, which I have used ever since. IMO, JetBrains IDEs are unbeatable (but YMMV); if I could persuade work to use Clion, or afford to buy the web development stuff for myself, I would switch immediately ... ->

Comment: ... That being said, go with whichever you are familiar with. There *_may_* be some obscure feature which one offers, but the other not, but that's unlikely to outweigh the advantages of familiarity.  Btw, since you are new, I will tell you that your (great) question, is off topic as it stands, please read [ask]. We expect you to give us a list of requirements, from which we can recommend some software, not to help you choose. Such questions are always closed. I would advise you to reword this one.  Welcome aboard, though; we need more Python help around her :-)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between PyCharm and Visual Studio code is that **PyCharm is an IDE and VS code is a text editor**. That doesn't mean that one is better than the other, but PyCharm is geared more toward large projects, while VS code is geared more towards smaller projects. As with all code editor choices, it's largely based on personal preference which one you use, so pick the one you're more comfortable with (or use both).

Comment: VS Code is an IDE

Comment: The boundary between IDE and editor is very, very fuzzy. VS Code is definitely closer to IDE than Notepad++. Sometimes you can find a feature in VS Code (especially with extensions) that some bigger IDE doesn't have. Regardless of what you think of as the boundary (if any), it's just not very useful to say "this one's an IDE and that one's an editor" when OP has obviously used both and to *them* both are under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is -- PyCharm is great if you mainly do local development. It has better code analysis support, better git integration, better refactoring tools, and better autocomplete; also, it is easier to see documentation, function API's, analyze various types of tests, and so on.

However, if you need some type of remote work (working on a remote server, deploying, docker integration...) then VSCode is far better. PyCharm claims to have some of these features in the pro version, but IMHO these remote-features seem to be bad, buggy, unfinished or non-existent (as of June 2021).